# Types of inverse transformations

Tags: spss, data-transformation, kurtosis

In performing an inverse transformation to correct for skewness/kurtosis in SPSS, it asks me to choose what "type" of inverse transformation and I have no idea what the differences between these transformations are. Is there any documentation on this or does anyone know the difference offhand? I couldn't find anything in the standard help files.

Even if you don't know the specific options in SPSS, if you know anything about inverse transformations, that would be helpful too.

Comment: In SPSS "inverse" variously means "reciprocal" (i.e., the transformation $x \to 1/x$), of which there is only one (making it doubtful you would be asked for a "type" in this context), and "functional inverse" (i.e., the inverse of $f:x \to y$ is the function $f^{-1}:y \to x$), which is very general and conceivably could have many "types."  The latter shows up in the context of variable transformations and link functions for generalized linear models, among other places.  Could you tell us what SPSS procedure you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse transformation is defined by SPSS as : Inverse transformation: compute inv = 1 / (x). (e.g., see [this search](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AoxyfusFx5D3V9.Hf3QzUK.bvZx4?p=INVERSE+TRANSFORMATIONS+IN+SPSS&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-701)) . It is one case of the class of transformations generally referred to as Power Transformations designed to uncouple dependence between the expect value and the variability.

[image]

Since there are no requirements for the observed series to be transformed to meet some Gaussian requirement BUT rather that the errors of a suitable model must do so , one should carefully apply this "medication/remedy". Now if your underlying model is Y=u + e then and only then should you be concerned with using any transformation on the original series.