# Multivariate ARIMA with regression

Tags: r, arima, multivariate-regression

I have a dataset covering daily data for 3 years (3x365 rows) for multiple attributes TotalPhoneCall (main attribute that I want to predict), Christmas day, weekend, weekday, Easter, 4th_july, etc.(some are seasonal).

I would like to predict TotalPhoneCall for the following month. I have to use ARIMA with regression. I may filter out unnecessary attributes if needed.  How can I do this in R?

Comment: Am I right that TotalPhoneCall is the only unknown, random variable?  That is, you know for the future exactly which days are christmas day, weekend, weekday, etc. (or putting it another way, there are no other explanatory variables you haven't mentioned).

Comment: All data including TotalPhoneCall has 3x365 rows. Its a m x n sized rectangular matrix. I have no info for future attributes for christmas day etc. I want to forecast TotalPhoneCall attribute only for the next 1 month. Not sure of what im doing but I tried "fit2<-arima(data.TotalPhoneCall, order = c(1, 1, 0), xreg=2:length(data))" and it gave me an error:  
Error in arima(data $ TotalPhoneCall, order = c(1, 1, 0), xreg = 2:length(data)) : 
  lengths of 'x' and 'xreg' do not match

Comment: I don't think you've understood my comment.  I was confused by your 3x365 but now I understand this to mean you have 1095 observations.  How many columns are in your data, and what are they, apart from "TotalPhoneCall"?  I interpret your question as, for example, one of the columns is "Christmas", which is TRUE on 25 December and FALSE otherwise.  And I meant that you don't need the model to forecast future values of Christmas, as you can consult this in a calender.

Comment: The error message you are getting is reasonably self-explanatory.  The xreg argument needs to have the same number of observations as TotalPhoneCall.  If my understanding of your data is right, it should consist, for example, of the matrix of explanatory variables like Christmas, Weekend, and 4_July.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Some users supply brief subsets of the data, to help readers understand the structure of their data. That might help here.

Comment: I wanted to give an easier explanation of the data but you got confused (sorry:/) Here is the actual data and I want to predict 30 more values on TS1
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AiDb3EV0gzlEdERaeXRiMnBGMXRZQldYNllJQ05aMnc&output=html

Comment: BTW Is the link visible? Maybe it is filtered?

Answer (score 1):

Your data set / design matrix tells a lot about your assumptions. You are explicitly assuming that week days have a common effect and weekends have a common effect. It is much more general to estimate the individual effects for each day and upon finding a common pattern to possibly reduce the design matrix accordingly.

You are implicitly assuming that

- there are no lead or lag effects around the known holidays that you are considering,
- there are no Pulses, Level Shifts  and/or Local Time Trends,
- the day-of-the-week effect is constant over the 1126 observations,
- there is no particular week-of-the-year effect by only introducing monthly indicators,
- the parameters of the model don’t change over time,
- the error variance is constant over time
- there is no need for ARIMA structure to render the final model’s residuals uncorrelated.

Other than these items, you are good to go!

In a positive note I would strongly suggest that you find a consultant or a program/approach/solution that speaks to some/all of the above considerations. I would start with [http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf](http://www.unc.edu/%7Ejbhill/tsay.pdf) .

after receipt of your data ..

The term Multivariate Arima is synonymous to VECTOR ARIMA i.e. multiple endogenous series. your problem has 1 endogenous (output) series thus and multiple inputs. This is called a Transfer Function. I note (but ignored) that you had negative phone calls. The data

[image]

One can suggest Holiday impacts and identify lead and lag structure around these events. In addition, there may be unusual activity that needs to be isolated/accounted for in order to get robust estimates of the daily effects/the monthly effects, the day-of-the-month effects, the week of the month effects. Following is the Actual-Fit-Forecast graph

[image]

and the residual plot

[image]

A plot of the forecasts for the next 21 days is presented here.

[image]

The actual equation is presented here in two parts

[image]

and

[image]

In summary your model has the following characteristics. [image]. In summary the third week of the month is statistically significant along with two level shifts at periods 5/15/09 and 5/20/10. Additionally, your series is impacted positively on Thursday and Monday and negatively on Saturday. There is a strong impact due to some specific months of the year and a few holidays.

Comment: The strong skewness of the residuals suggests analyzing the roots of the counts instead of the raw counts themselves. Surprisingly, your first plot indicates many of these counts (the "Actuals") in the legend are negative, bottoming out around $-25$. That's mysterious, but I presume there may be some mislabeling of the y axis.

Comment: @huber I had previously commented about the strange negative phone calls. In response to your suggestion about taking roots ( meaning square roots) please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13095/types-of-inverse-transformations which shows that this specific transformation requires that the variance of the residuals be proportional to the Expected Value of Y.If this c an be verified then your suggestion of taking roots ( after making all the values positive) might be applicable.