# auto.arima with regressors

Tags: time-series, forecasting

A simple question, but I have not found it anywhere. I have worked with time series for a while, but am new to R. I want to predict future values of Y (all I care about are the forecast) when I believe certain regressors impact these results. I understand that auto.arima allows this capacity, but what is not clear to me is if to use this capacity you first have to forecast the future x values and provide this to R (essentially pre-whitening the data like multivariate ARIMA)  or whether auto.arima is projecting the future values of the regressors itself (essentially pre-whitening the regressors for you).

I think you use a training data set for the X in the auto.arima that you provide, to determine the Arima model. Then you use a projected  future group of X (which you again provide)as the regressor in the predict statement.

Something like

packagefit<- auto.arima(Y,xreg=train_x)
forecast_1<- forecast(packagefit,xreg=predicted_X)

Comment: If it predicted them for you, they wouldn't be *exogenous*.

Comment: I am sorry Chris Haug I am not sure what 'it' means in this context. I understand the predictors have to be exogenous, but not how it relates to my question. The problem I have is some authors suggest you have to use future, projected levels of predictors to predict future Y in ARIMA, when using regressors. I don't understand why this would be so, ARIMA uses present levels of Y normally to predict future Y.

Comment: Exogenous means that the dynamics of those processes are not modeled (they are "external" to the model), therefore your model cannot forecast them at all. The model of $Y$ is conditioned on those regressors. Therefore, 1) you must provide future values and 2) the prediction intervals and predictive distribution in general assume that those future values are known exactly, without uncertainty. If you want a model like ARIMA but that models multiple series endogeneously, consider VAR.

Comment: thanks. That makes sense to me. My problem, being new to using multivariate ARIMA is that one of the first authors I ran into seemed to not be providing future values for X in using xreg. He used a training set to build the model and then (I thought) the whole data set (without predicted X) to forecast. And univariate ARIMA of course only requires existing values not future ones (you use the ARIMA to predict future ones). I was wrong in my assumptions. Your comments on exogenous variables make sense in that regard.

Comment: It's not *multivariate* ARIMA, there is only one *endogenous* process. I don't know which author you're referring to, but one possibility is what some call *direct forecasting* which is when you lag the exogenous regressors so that the value you need in the forecast period is still the "future" of that regressor but is actually already known. Another is that the regressor is actually known in advance (trends, seasonal dummies, holidays, etc). It could also have simply been done incorrectly (e.g. by taking exact future values of an exogeneous variable that isn't actually yet observed).

Comment: thank you. I wanted to clarify a point. I am looking at cases where you are conducting arima with multiple predictors. Isn't that the same thing as multivariate Arima or Arimax as I have seen it called?

Comment: I have never seen the term "multivariate ARIMA" used anywhere. "Multivariate" refers to the number of endogenous series; the number of exogenous series is not really relevant. You could refer to VARMA as "multivariate ARMA", but that's not what you're talking about. ARIMAX is also not what you have here (it is a different way of adding exogenous variables to an ARIMA model).

Comment: Here is an example of it being used that way. http://web.mit.edu/11.951/oldstuff/albacete/Other_Documents/Europe%20Transport%20Conference/applied_methods_in_tra/a_multivariate_ari1399.pdf here is another https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45993/multivariate-arima-with-regression